# Match regex value to exact length, multiple groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm rather inexperienced in regex, but what I need to do is match a URL in order to route it correctly. Examples:

`/2013/06/article-title`

`/2013/06`

`/2013`

Are all possible paths I need to check for. I did some research and found a little bit about checking for an exact length. But when I tried to modify it for my own use, it returns false.

Here's what I had for the simplest:

`^\\~/([0-9]{4})$`

Any ideas? Thanks.

For reference, here's the code that tries to match it:

```cs
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;

Regex r = new Regex(regexp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
m = r.Match(url);

return m.Success;
```

Comment: why not `String.Split('/')`?

Comment: I can use `.Split()` to get the groups, but I had to match the URL so it didn't try to go to the other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this with groups `(?:..)` and question marks that make groups optional :

```
^/[0-9]{4}(?:/[0-9]{2}(?:/[\w-]+)?)?$
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot! Though I did have to make it `^~/[0-9]{4}(?:/[0-9]{2}(?:/[\\w-]+)?)?$` to escape the \ and add the ~ to match the URL format. Otherwise it worked great. :)